# TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'url'

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdrivermanager-python

Executing below code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
browser  = webdriver.Chrome

browser.get('https://soysocio.bocajuniors.com.ar/index.php')
```

Error:

```
[line 7] TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'url'
```

How can i solve it? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

you should change `webdriver.Chrome` to `webdriver.Chrome()`

Chrome is a class, not an instance.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
browser  = webdriver.Chrome()

browser.get('https://soysocio.bocajuniors.com.ar/index.php')
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to execute the Chrome driver.

`browser  = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')`  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.

You can find examples of how Chrome driver used [here](https://www.syntaxtechs.com/blog/learn-the-usage-of-selenium-chromedriver-steps-to-run-selenium-tests-on-chrome-browser)

Answer (score 0):

```
browser  = webdriver.Chrome
```

browser should be instantiation

```
browser  = webdriver.Chrome()
```